# Calculating the number of processes created from fork

Tags: process, operating-system, fork

Hi I m facing difficulty in calculating the total number of processes in the code below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
    { 
        int pid = fork();

        if(pid < 0)
            exit()

        if(pid % 2 == 0) 
            fork(); 
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: make a count and do count++ after any fork()

Comment: I have to calculate the maximum and average number of processes created, now my doubt is that, is the pid assigned to the processes in a random fashion so that maximum processes would be created when each processes has a even PID? thanks in advance!

Comment: you can see this https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork and make getppid / getpid  to see the PID after fork.

Comment: The PID for the new processes will be randomly assigned. If child pid of first process is even, then that results many further new process to be forked. And they in turn will continue the for loop from the value of `i` which again forks and depend on evenness of pid.

Comment: Also, note that the return value of fork for the child will be 0. And hence `if(pid % 2 == 0)` will be true for the child process created after the first `fork` in the loop.

Comment: @Prabhu not true.
fork returns the pid of the new process to the parent.

The new process might have an even pid.

Comment: @TonyTannous, what would be the value of pid in the child process after `fork()`?

Comment: @Prabhu as far as I know, the return value of fork for child process is 0, the return value o fork to parent process is the actual pid of the child process.

Comment: @TonyTannous, yes, thats what I was indicating. If PID is even, parent of first fork will fork again. Also the child of the first fork as well will fork.